# Eigen 2D cross product

Tags: c++, vector, geometry, eigen, eigen3

Can Eigen do a 2D cross product?

I was trying to replace this code:

```
Eigen::Vector2f a, b;
float result = a.x()*b.y() - b.x()*a.y();
```

With this:

```
Eigen::Vector2f a, b;
float result = a.cross(b);
```

However, this gives me the following error:

`error C2338: THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE`

**Update**

Of course *Avi Ginsburg* is right and its not really defined. So to clarify: What I'm looking for is the length of the cross product (basically the sine of the angle between the vectors, if I understand it correctly).

Comment: This question has already been considered, see this [feature request](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1037).

Comment: What do you have against the first solution ? You can consider computing the 2x2 determinant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just thought it would be nicer to use a predefined function for such a "standard" computation, instead of doing the computation myself...

Comment: For the 2x2 case, using generic functions is most probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a cross product is a vector, not a float. And anyway, a cross product in 2D doesn't make sense. In 2D the result vector would have to be perpendicular to both `a` and `b` and they already define the plane, so the result would have to be in the 3rd dimension.

Comment: Thanks, Updated my question

Comment: What Jan really wants is the exterior/outer product. This exists for any dimension. For 3D it is the dual of the cross product (pseudo vector) and for 2D the dual of a scalar (pseudo scalar). It would be handy to have this in Eigen. The best way would be to return a row vector for column vector arguments and vice versa. (For 2D unfortunately you cannot distinguish pseudo scalars from scalars just by their dimension (1x1)) See Geometric Algebra for a more rigorous notation.